# configure jellyfish issue cannot run C compiled programs with MinGW g++

Tags: g++, mingw, msys

I am trying to install jellyfish using GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys).  I have `gcc` and g++`with`version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)`.  When I run the configure file I get the error below:

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/c/Users/bjwil/Downloads/jellyfish-2.2.10':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
./configure: line 38: sort: No such file or directory
./configure: line 35: sed: No such file or directory
```

Then inside the config.log file I get starting with first error after `COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe`:

```
configure:3778: gcc -V >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3789: $? = 1
configure:3778: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3789: $? = 1
configure:3809: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3831: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3835: $? = 0
configure:3883: result: yes
configure:3886: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3888: result: a.exe
configure:3894: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3901: gcc -o conftest.exe    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3905: $? = 0
configure:3927: result: .exe
configure:3949: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3957: gcc -o conftest.exe    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3961: $? = 0
configure:3968: ./conftest.exe
./configure: line 3970: ./conftest.exe: Permission denied
configure:3972: $? = 126
configure:3979: error: in `/c/Users/bjwil/Downloads/jellyfish-2.2.10':
configure:3981: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

Works fine in Ubuntu 64-bit.

Comment: Is the "application experience service" disabled?

Comment: Have you tried with the files in a subdirectory of your MSYS home dir?

Comment: not sure how to check where the aes is disables or enabled, tried in msys sub direct is breaks here `checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in /c/msys64/home/jellyfish-2.3.0'`

Comment: Shouldn't there be a username in that path? Does `ls -l ~/jellyfish-2.3.0` work as expected?

Comment: You can make sure AES is enabled in `services.msc` (Windows)

Comment: Sorry I though you meant the home folder in msys.  I added to my user home now. But I do not even see AES under services.  It goes straight from App Readiness to Application Host in alpha order.  I found that it is enable under Task Scheduler.